# Spring - ServletWebRequest.getHeaderValues() not returning all headers

Tags: java, spring, servlets, http-headers, request-headers

I have my controller function setup like so

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test/index.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView prepareView(HttpServletRequest request, @RequestHeader HttpHeaders header)
```

I was getting a null pointer exception from this at

```
 org.springframework.web.method.annotation.RequestHeaderMapMethodArgumentResolver.resolveArgument(RequestHeaderMapMethodArgumentResolver.java:72)
```

so I decompiled this class file and stepped through in debug mode. The problematic section of the code looks like this:

```
/* 70 */       for (Iterator<String> iterator = webRequest.getHeaderNames(); iterator.hasNext();) {
/* 71 */         String headerName = (String)iterator.next();
/* 72 */         for (String headerValue : webRequest.getHeaderValues(headerName)) {
/* 73 */           result.add(headerName, headerValue);
/*    */         }
/*    */       }
```

`webRequest` is an object of type `NativeWebRequest`. So in line 70 I can see that `webRequest.getHeaderNames()` is returning the
request headers i see in chrome network tab for example.

**Apparently the load balancer (netscaler) is inserting some headers after the request is created (i'll call this `x-model`) that I cannot see in chrome.**

Following this trace I see all the standard RequestHeaders go through and be added with no issues (i.e `Accept`, `Cookie`, `Host`, etc). However, eventually the iterator on line 70 reaches the `x-model` header. Then in line 72, `webRequest.getHeaderValues('x-model')` is called, and this returns null as there is no header called x-model is found. This causes a null pointer on the enhanced foreach.

Why is there a discrepancy between what is returned by `ServletWebRequest.getHeaderNames()` and `ServletWebRequest.getHeaderValues(headerName)`? What can I do to resolve this issue?

**I have noticed that when I look at the iterator created in line 70, there is a keySet hashmap containing `[cookie, connection, accept-language, host, accept, user-agent, accept-encoding, referer, x-model, x-tenant, upgrade-insecure-requests]`. However, the table entry does not contain an entry for x-model. Please see attached image for the 2 objects i refer to**

I am using Java 7 and Spring 4.0.7

[image]

What is the difference between table and entryset here? Why does entryset contain the `x-model` entry but table does not?

Comment: does this header `x-model` has value?

Comment: it does, but the value is an object when i check the iterator

Comment: Actually, weirdly enough I cannot see this entry in the iterator. But it must be there since it gets selected

Comment: ah i see now that it is in the keySet but not an actual entry in the table, do you know where this is set? I assume within spring still though

Comment: can explain a bit more? value is `KeySet?`

Comment: So when I look at the value of my `iterator`, i see that it is a `HashMap`. The property `Hashmap.KeySet` of this hashmap contains `x-model`. However, `Hashmap.Entry` does not have an entry for `x-model`

Comment: Can you see what headers are sent in chrome/postman? Is x-model your custom header?

Comment: that is completely weird

Comment: yes x-model is my custom header. I cannot see this header in chrome/postman because this header is added by netscaler after the request is sent by chrome/postman

Comment: well probably the header is being inserted with a null value, if you can find the part where that is done i would like to see it

Comment: well i guess that fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was actually because someone had added an override to `HttpServletRequestWrapper.getHeaderNames()` which is what spring uses to retrieve the list of headernames to support a wrapper header which, but did not override `HttpServletRequestWrapper.getHeaders()` which is what spring uses to find the value of the header

Comment: really good catch. I struggled for half a day searching through WebRequest and it's impl but you answer made my day! Thanks a lot.